# Use type parameters in return value container types

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to create a set of functions that allow their callers to convert runtime-variable values into compile-time-specific equivalents. In my case, the runtime variables are Windows IInspectables and the conversion process is commonly referred to as "unboxing" (though for the purpose of my C++ question those details are merely illustrative). I want the conversion functions to work for scalars (e.g. bool, int, double), containers (e.g. optional, pair, tuple, vector) and container combinations (e.g. vector<pair<bool, int>>). The container unboxing functions should use the unboxing functions for the contained types.

I know it's possible to express the desired container type via overload resolution on out parameters, e.g.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Unbox(/* in */ IInspectable* boxedValue, /* out */ std::pair<T1, T2>& unboxedValue)

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Unbox(/* in */ IInspectable* boxedValue, /* out */ std::tuple<T1, T2>& unboxedValue)
```

Is it possible to do the same via return values instead of out parameters?  I know this is incorrect/unusable, but conceptually I want to define …

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<T1, T2> Unbox(IInspectable* insp);

template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::tuple<T1, T2> Unbox(IInspectable* insp);
```

… in such a way that the caller controls whether a pair or a 2-element tuple gets created. If possible, what's the right pattern to achieve this? It's acceptable if the unboxing functions were (static) methods of (parameterized) structs.

Comment: `template<typename... Ts> std::tuple<Ts...> Unbox(IInspectable*);` should be possible. issue is to disambiguate your functions if you want return pair/tuple.

Comment: `template<typename T> T Unbox(IInspectable*);` and do the dispatch inside the function with call as `Unbox<std::pair<bool, int>>`.

Comment: In your working solution you are responsible for making the choice of how you want `boxedValue` to be unboxed, and you do the choice by providing a second argument of approrpriate type. In your desired solution, the simple question is: who/what is responsible for the choice, if not you? You still need to let the function know what you want in output. And you can do so by providing a template parameter, as in @super's third option. I don't think there's a way to get the signature you desire for two functions with the same name. Unless the return type somehow depends on `IInspectable`...

Answer (score 2):

Either you just give them different names, like

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::pair<T1, T2> UnboxPair(IInspectable* insp);

template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::tuple<T1, T2> UnboxTuple(IInspectable* insp);
```

Another option is to pass the full return type to the function

```
template<typename T>
T Unbox(IInspectable* insp) {
    using T1 = std::tuple_element_t<0, T>; // works on std::pair and std::array as
    using T2 = std::tuple_element_t<1, T>; // well as std::tuple
    ...
}

auto myTuple = Unbox<std::tuple<int, int>>(...);
```

Yet a third options would be to pass the containing type as a template template parameter.

```
template<template <typename...> typename Container, typename T1, typename T2>
Container<T1, T2> Unbox(IInspectable* insp);

auto myPair = Unbox<std::pair, int, int>(...);
```

Comment: I like "tag parameter" option: `template <typename> struct Tag{};` and then `template <typename T1, template T2> std::pair<T1, T2> Unbox(Tag<std::pair<T1, T2>>, IInspectable*)`

Comment: @super 1/5 Thanks for your response! I'm going to stick with enabling the caller to control whether a pair or a 2-element tuple gets created as a representation of the fundamental problem I'm asking about here.

Comment: @super 2/5 Re: "give them different names":

That's not really an option for me as this is part of a solution in which the conversion target type is being deduced.

Comment: @super 3/5 Re: "pass the full return type to the function":

That to me would be the ideal solution - I just don't know how go about it. 
Assuming you suggest to define one template to create a pair and one to create a tuple, how do you avoid the two templates clashing (in my case, msvc C2995 'function template has already been defined')? Perhaps I can activate the appropriate template via std::enable_if, or create the desired container via a 'constexpr if' in the template body?

Comment: @super 4/5 Re: "template template parameter"

I tried that, but assuming this is meant to lead to partial instantiations for the desired container type, I can't work out the syntax for that (running, for instance, into msvc C2768 'illegal use of explicit template arguments').

Comment: @super 5/5 Sorry for being dense, but could you perhaps show the code that works for a scalar, for pairs and for 2-element tuples?

Comment: @Eightbitmind Not really sure what part is unclear. I've already given three examples on approaches and what the function would look like. *That's not really an option for me as this is part of a solution in which the conversion target type is being deduced.* It's not possible to have compile-time deduction based on a run-time vallue like `IInspectable`, so not sure what you mean there.

Answer (score 0):

I like "tag parameter" option:

```
// Possibly in "private" namespace

// structure for tag dispatching.
template <typename> struct Tag{};

// Overloads of the different Unbox implementations
// Allow custom-point for user classes.
template <typename T1, template T2>
std::pair<T1, T2> Unbox(Tag<std::pair<T1, T2>>, IInspectable*)
{
    // ...
}

template <typename Ts...>
std::tuple<Ts...> Unbox(Tag<std::tuple<Ts...>>, IInspectable*)
{
    // ...
}


float Unbox(Tag<float>, IInspectable*)
{
    // ...
}
// any other overloads, even a fallback for Tag<T>
```

so usage would be:

```
auto p = Unbox(Tag<std::pair<bool, float>>{}, inspectable);
auto t = Unbox(Tag<std::tuple<bool, float>>{}, inspectable);
```

To have your another syntax, you might then do:

```
template <typename T>
T Unbox(IInspectable* inspectable)
{
    return Unbox(Tag<T>{}, inspectable);
}
```

so usage would become:

```
auto p = Unbox<std::pair<bool, float>>(inspectable);
auto t = Unbox<std::tuple<bool, float>>(inspectable);
```

- Note: `Tag` syntax might be simpler in template function, when those overload are member:

  `template <typename T> void (T& obj) { obj.Unbox(Tag<int>{}, inspectable); }`

  versus

  `template <typename T> void (T& obj) { obj.template Unbox<int>(inspectable); }`